# Get DOM element in an iframe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, getelementbyid

I have two documents, one of which is embedded into the other with an iframe. I'm trying to use this code to access the img tag inside the iframe, however, I cannot use the document.getElementById function on the iframe element:

```
iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
spaces = iframes[0].contentWindow.document;
spaces = spaces.getElementsByTagName("img")
for (var i=0, max=spaces.length; i < max; i++) {
     alert(spaces[i].innerHTML)
}
alert(spaces)
var x = document.getElementById("frame");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y = y.document;
alert(y.body.innerHTML)
```

spaces returns [object HTMLCollection] and y returns [object HTMLDocument]

Comment: try to provide more code like the html behind the iframe

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're on the same domain as your iframe content, you can use

```
document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById(...)
```

If you're not on the same domain, you can't access/manipulate iframe content for security reasons. Otherwise malicious folks could throw up an iframe that looks like Facebook or something and steal other folk's info.

If you're not on the same domain but own both domains you're using, you can set up [messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) between the two frames. And use the parent to message the child for information/manipulation.

Comment: This is returning null for me. I should add that the embedded html page is also embedding a youtube video, but I am not accessing that. The interesting thing is that when I remove the ".getElementById("space")' part, it returns [object HTMLDocument], but when I add it it returns null.

Comment: I bit more debugging reveals that the "document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document" object only has one property, location.